# Can a block element contain another block element?

Tags: css, html

Started playing around with html yesterday and I now have a question.

Whats the reason why I can't have two block elements inside of each eachother?

Comment: Yes, you can have nested block elements. You may need to use floats or positioning to keep them from stacking though.

Comment: I think you may be confusing having a block element child of a block element (good) with a block element that is a child of an inline element (will probably render fine; but violates standards).

Comment: Nothing catastrophic will happen if you just try something in html/css - so just try it! Make sure it's valid to do what you've actually done by using the w3c validator https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: If the block elements are empty, and have no content, they will collapse and will not be visible at all..

Comment: You can check by yourself by putting a `div` inside another `div`, which is standard practice.

Comment: What do u mean @RobertC Im not sure I follow you 100%

<h1> this is a header <p> this is a paragraph </p> </h1>

Why would this line of code not work?

Comment: That *would* work; they are both block-level elements.  You can *also* place a block-level element inside an inline element and it will probably render fine; but it would return an error when checking compliance

Comment: @MilleGloerfeltTarp - That would *work*, but it would not be valid. Heading elements like H1 must not contain p elements because it's considered contradictory from a semantics perspective.

Comment: Yes..and no. You can for instance put a div or a `p` in a `p` but it's unsemantic and the native browsers will force the `p` to close *whether you do it or not* so that the div is not enclosed any more. This leads to unpredictable results,

Answer (score 1):

yes a block element can contain another block element.
The default display value for most elements is **block** or **inline**.

```css
.parent-div{
  display:block;
  background:#000;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child-div{
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:#fff;
  margin-top:25px;
  margin-left:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
<div class="child-div">

</div>
</div>
```